# Designing custom sign in flow/activity for Cognito

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I am following the Amazon cognito user signin guide here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in-email-and-password.html#email-and-password-config-overview

It all works perfectly, but the default activity they launch is ugly and surprisingly hard to use. The code they use to launch this activity is

```
    AuthUIConfiguration config =
            new AuthUIConfiguration.Builder().userPools(true).build();

    Context context = SplashActivity.this;
    SignInActivity.startSignInActivity(context, config);
```

I would like to build my own sign in flow. Is that even possible? Is there a tutorial out there on how to do this?

I am cant their flow, because when I follow the link to SignInActivity, I get `...\.grade\caches\ modules-2\files-2.1\com.amazonaws\aws-android-sdk-auth-ui\2.6.0\991ae12d55d8733e2ebb4b3e4c30a6cc2ee42d3a\aws-android-sdk-auth-ui-2.6.0-sources.jar!\com\amazonaws\mo` and the file is locked for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SignInActivity is just another activity.  You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/04a8494ccc32914e1041d52829169168bb8dd91d/aws-android-sdk-auth-ui/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/ui/SignInActivity.java).  There is no reason you can't take a copy of this activity, then replace the UI with your own UI.  This is probably the easiest mechanism to adjust the UI to your liking.

Comment: Hello Adrian. I have created a new SignInActivity in my project and built my own UI. How can I use the views (signIn, signUp button views, username edittext etc.,) and build the login flow.

Comment: Use practically the same code for the process as the AWS Mobile tutorials and walk-throughs.  Just replace SignInActivity with your SignInActivity replacement.

Answer (score 3):

We have recently worked on the AWS mobile app and we know that only cloning the SigninActivity Code won't work. You would need to clone [SigninView](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/04a8494ccc32914e1041d52829169168bb8dd91d/aws-android-sdk-auth-ui/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/ui/SignInView.java), [UserPoolSignInView](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/04a8494ccc32914e1041d52829169168bb8dd91d/aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/userpools/UserPoolSignInView.java), and [CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/04a8494ccc32914e1041d52829169168bb8dd91d/aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobile/auth/userpools/CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.java).
We had added a progressbar in the layout and set the visibility on the click event of the buttonview.

I hope these instructions should help.

Cheers,
Kapil

Comment: Great point - I don't suppose you have a blog or anything about your process?

Comment: @iPragmatech Solutions: Can you please elaborate your approach?

Comment: @AdrianHall We were working on the blog/sample source code but caught up with other tasks. Share your email address and we shall send you the source code or inform you once we upload the sample code on GitHub.

Comment: @heisenberg91Can you ask a specific question. I guess we already discuss the approach which is to Override the required features from these class.

If you are looking for end solution then you may need to wait :(

Comment: @AdrianHall  here is the blog with sample code to customize the signin for AWS cognito https://www.ipragmatech.com/aws-cognito-custom-signin-ui/. Feel free to comment there or improve the source code.